# PHP Array Search Returns Empty Key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to use `array_search` to find the key of a value in an array, I have the following simple code:

```
$current_user_existing_shopping_bag_string          = '1446784/-/3/-/£797.00(_)902982/-/4/-/£148.80(_) ';
$current_user_existing_shopping_bag_array           = explode('(_)', $current_user_existing_shopping_bag_string);
$key                                                = array_search($current_user_existing_shopping_bag_array, '902982');
echo $key;
```

However I have no idea why this doesn't return the key of the value in the array, it should though. I've been trying various solutions for hours now and still no luck.

Anybody able to give me a pointer why this doesn't return the key for the value in the array?

Thanks

Comment: Do ( and ) have a special meaning in the explode() method?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: It's used to separate the string elements into 'blocks'

Comment: My expected output is '1446784/-/3/-/£797.00'

Comment: array search takes the value (not the array) as first argument.

Comment: @self, yea I know, that's why my first argument is the array

Comment: No it is not right. You should read the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `array_search` compares strings using `===` operator, not regex or `strpos` of any kind.

You search for `902982` but string is `902982/-/4/-/£148.80`, and therefore they are not equal in any way.

For what you want to achieve, you can use [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php):

```
$result = preg_grep('/' . preg_quote($search) . '/', $current_user_existing_shopping_bag_array);
```

Then you can get the keys you need from the resulting array.

Comment: It is only filter-like regex search, and returns array indexed with original keys, so you can just take the keys you found and then delete  them from the original array.

Comment: Okay, so I'm still a bit confused, the result I get in $result is an array

Comment: How I'm I supposed to use the info in this array?

Comment: @user2028856 Yes. `$result` has all elements of the original array with their respective key where the pattern was found (here: the number). So you can do sth like `$.._bag_array = array_diff($.._bag_array, $result);` to remove them from the original array

Comment: @user2028856 It contains key-value pairs from the original array, matching string you are searching. RTFM

Comment: This returns the same result as if you used array_filter with preg_match.

Comment: @DavidStone it is quite shorter, and your solution reinvents it.

Comment: And in the terms of performance, it does not use closure to perform this search, so it should perform somewhat faster